# Why won't this skip non-numeric values?

Tags: vba

I am trying to iterate over an array and skip the non-numeric values, I have put an if loop inside a for loop with the intention that it should identify non numeric values if so +1 to the iterator, however it is not working, producing no error message as to why

```
For i = 1 To 780

    If Not IsNumeric(Worksheets("sheet").Cells(6 + i, 6)) Then
       i = i + 1
    End If

Worksheets("one").Cells(6 + i, 6) = Worksheets("one").Cells(6 + i, 6) * Worksheets("two").Cells(3 + i, 6)      

Next
```

I am new to VBA and do not understand why this wouldn't work

Comment: Modifying the loop variable inside the loop body is asking for trouble and off-by-one bugs. Exactly what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incrementing your loop counter inside the loop skips the ***next*** item, not the current one.  Assuming that `....` is the code you want to execute if the value is numeric, reverse your condition and only run that code for numeric values:

```
For i = 1 To 780
    If IsNumeric(Worksheets("sheet").Cells(6 + i, 6)) Then
       '....    
    End If
Next
```

Note that your code also assumes that empty cells have a value of `0`.  If `.Cells(6 + i, 6)` is empty, it will *return* `Empty`, which will implicitly cast to 0:

```
Range("A1").ClearContents
Debug.Print IsNumeric(Range("A1")) '<-- True
```

If you need to ignore empty cells also, you'll need an additional test:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("sheet").Cells(6 + i, 6)) Then
    If IsNumeric(Worksheets("sheet").Cells(6 + i, 6)) Then
       '....
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You code review guys come into my house and wax poetic, and thus give a better answer.  Why I aughta' ...... sheeeeeesh :)

Comment: @ScottCraner - LOL.  Just trying to pre-emptively answer the OP's next `n` questions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for the negative look for the positive:

```
For i = 1 To 780

    If IsNumeric(Worksheets("sheet").Cells(6 + i, 6)) Then
       'Do your code when it is numeric
       'It will skip to the next loop if not numeric
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object to loop through your range "numeric" cells only:

```
    Dim cell As Range        
    With Worksheets("sheet")
        For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(7, 6), .Cells(786, 6)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

            ' your code for numeric values

        Next cell
    End With
```